# Cordova hooks order

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hook, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

On the Cordova website a see a long list of hooks in alphabetical order, but what is the correct order in which they trigger and get executed?

I'm trying to add the `cordova.js` script to the `index.html` file's `head` before build/compile.

What happens first between `before_build` and `before_compile`, and why?
What's the difference between the terms `build` and `compile` here?

Does `build` mean copying all the assets before `compile` the platform code? So my hook should be in the `before_build` directory?

Please confirm or correct me if I'm wrong.

Also a correct order of the hooks will be helpful to everybody since the documentation is unclear :)

EDIT:

Does `cordova-cli` automatically add the `cordova.js` script for me eventually, in the case it's missing? Because I was testing the hook, and even if it didn't work the script is already present in the html file.

Comment: Apparently yes, it's already adding the `cordova.js` file for me, even if I didn't manually put it in my original `index.html` file. Which is a good thing during development, so that I don't see a 404 Error in the console.

Even if I solved my problem with the hook script, it would be cool to know in which order all the hooks get executed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compile is the native compilation step while prepare is when Cordova does all the copying of preferences and assets. Build is a shortcut for running both of these. You can see this is the order that hooks are fired. (Tested on Cordova 5.4.0)

On Cordova build:

```
before_build
before_prepare
after_prepare
before_compile
after_compile
after_build
```

On Cordova prepare:

```
before_prepare
after_prepare
```

On Cordova compile:

```
before_compile
after_compile
```

On Cordova run:

```
before_run
before_prepare
after_prepare
after_run
```

Interestingly `run` appears to fire the prepare hooks, but not the compile (or build) hooks. This could just be a bug.

Comment: `run` shouldn't compile again if it's already been built. That's what appened I suppose

Comment: `run` does compile, this is indeed a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8287